# WPF/C# Dataset does not match database

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

The Dataset I created in my WPF application does not match the records I have in my database.

I had to manually update that table the dataset uses, and since then I have duplicates. The dataset still shows old data I don't have in database anymore.

Any idea how to refresh the dataset? Is there any cache I can empty in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how this relates to WPF, but:

```
Dataset.Reset();
Adaptor.Fill(Dataset.table);
```

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Do you have a code sample?

Comment: My bad, it is correct and solved my problem, I did a mistake trying what you pointed out. Thank you!